# iOS - Find index of a cell in a section

Tags: ios, row, tableview

I have a table divided by dynamically changing alphabetically ordered sections. When I press a cell, I want it to expand.

What is happening is, when I, for example, select cell1 in section 2, every cell1 in every section opens.

I know i need to get a value of indexpath.section and indexpath.row in the didselectrowforindexpath but how?

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NSString* letter = [letters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
NSArray* arrayForLetter = (NSArray*)[filteredTableData objectForKey:letter];
shu = (ShuDict*)[arrayForLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {

    if (!self.detailViewController) {
        self.detailViewController = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"DetailViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil];
    }
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.detailViewController animated:YES];
} else {

    NSString* letter = [letters objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSArray* arrayForLetter = (NSArray*)[filteredTableData objectForKey:letter];
    shu = (ShuDict*)[arrayForLetter objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"%@",shu);
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = shu.description;
    self.detailViewController.title = shu.title;

}

    if (selectedRow == indexPath.row) {
        lblDecs.hidden=NO;
        selectedRow = -1;

    }
    else{
        lblDecs.hidden = YES;
        selectedRow = indexPath.row;

    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

So this is my didSelectRowAtIndexPath method. I think the problem is selectedRow == indexpath.row because it doesn't include the index of the section?

Comment: can you show us how,
1. the sorting method works
2. how does the expansion works (does it flag it has been expanded then reload the table?)
please, thank you! :)

Comment: I saw that solution. It does not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think "lblDecs" is common. it not change on selection of any cell

```
// Original code
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
       .
       .
       .  
       .
   if (selectedRow == indexPath.row) {
        lblDecs.hidden=NO;
        selectedRow = -1;

    }
    else{
        lblDecs.hidden = YES;
        selectedRow = indexPath.row;

    }
 }
```

So you can directly show lblDecs

```
lblDecs.hidden=NO;
```

and hide in method

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    lblDecs.hidden=YES;
}
```

if lblDecs is different than use this

```
if ((selectedRow == indexPath.row) && (selectedSection == indexPath.section) ) {
        .
        .
        .
 }
```

Comment: Thanks man, if ((selectedRow == indexPath.row) && (selectedSection == indexPath.section) ) is what I needed!! Much love!